# What are the verbs, nouns adjectives that follow if/whether in English structures?

Tags: conjunctions

As there are certain structures in English of each word.similarly I am asking if/whether has certain verb structures or they follow certain pattern of verb, adjective, and noun .
 Ex I am happy whether you’re coming. ( happy is followed by whether )
I can’t say whether he’ll get back.( say is followed by whether)

Similarly what are other appropriate verb adjectives or noun for if/whether thanks a lot

Comment: "I am happy whether you’re coming" is nonsensical.

Comment: _Whether_ carries the (sometimes unspoken) alternative _or not_. Your sentence definitely needs the addition of 'or not'. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/whether-or-not-vs-whether

Comment: *I am uncertain whether you're coming* makes sense, but you can't replace *uncertain* with *happy*. However, the best way of figuring out which of *if* and *whether* to use is to learn what each of these words means, not to memorize a long list of verbs and adjectives associated with each of them. I assume that your first language uses the same word for both, like French does (*si*).

Comment: ...Uncertain (in Peter's example) is an adjective regularly taking the preposition 'about'. _I am uncertain about whether you're coming._ And in conversation especially, the 'about' is often dropped.

Comment: A general term might be "flowery language"